# Is it common to use the term “(hyper-)graph” for infinite or even uncountable vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

A (hyper-)graph is a set of vertices, with a set of (possibly more than size two-)subsets of vertices called edges. I think usually the set of vertices is finite.

Is it common in graph theory to use the term (hyper-)graph to refer to a non-finite set of vertices?

Comment: @DonThousand I know that hypergraph has a defined meaning. I was asking about that defined meaning, i.e. whether hypergraphs can also have uncountable number of vertices.

Comment: From my experience, no, it is not common.

Comment: Furthermore, the vertices and edges of a hyper-graph are commonly called hyper-vertices and hyper-edges, not just vertices and edges. The terminology also varies when one talks about representations of hypergraphs (e.g. as dessins d'enfants=bipartite graphs or ribbon graphs).